# Python While Loop CPU demanding

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I don't want to bother people here with a simple question and also tell that I googled for information but I would like to get input from the people who as faced the same. It is stated that while loops in python slow down (http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop). I have a script which employs only one loop but that is quite important and in fact it really slows down. My first program was using 100 % CPU (Dual core!!!). I introduced a sleep() function on the loop and the CPU usage went down to 50 %. I cannot just keep increasing the sleep time, actually I would like to decrease it. Anyway, is there any 'trick' to make this while loop faster?

(The condition is whether a button is pressed or not on a user interface build on pyQt4)

Comment: It is physically impossible for a single threaded program to use 100% of both cores. Something else is using that second core.

Comment: I agree. Anyway it is obvious that this main while loop is killing my CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

The reference you linked to is misleading. The speed difference between the two samples will be minimal and usually not even noticeable if any real work is being done inside the loop.

It is the nature of *any* loop that it will use 100% of its allocated time until it's done. It doesn't matter if the loop is wickedly efficient or wildly inefficient. The only way around this is to call some OS function that makes it wait, such as the `sleep` that you tried.

The reason that modern OS GUI's are event driven is so that you don't have to wait in a loop for an event - you call a single function to wait for a message, and the OS gives the CPU to someone else until a message arrives. With a framework such as Qt this will be buried in what's called a message loop, and you'll need to provide the proper framework hooks to get the event routed to your own function.

Answer (score 0):

I will study on the information you gave me. But to keep the discussion here is the part of the code is slowing down :

```
while self.startButton.isChecked():
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.clear()                                                 
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.set_xlabel('Sensor #')
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.set_yscale('log', basey = 10)                                   
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.set_xlim(0, num_sensors + 1) 
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.set_xticks(range(1, num_sensors + 1)) 
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.set_xticklabels(sensorLabel, fontsize = 10)
    measure, read_s = [], []                       
    t = round((time() - initialTime), 1)           
    for i in range(num_sensors):
        read = self.ser.readline().strip()  
        measure.append(read)
        read = float(read) 
        read_s.append(read) 
        self.widget.canvas.ax.plot(t, read, plot_array[i])
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.scatter(range(1, num_sensors + 1), read_s, c = log10(read_s), s = 100) 
    self.widget.canvas.ax2.set_ylim(bottom = .8 * min(read_s))                            
    f.write(str(t) + '\t' + '\t'.join(measure) + '\n')  
    self.widget.canvas.ax.legend(loc = 'center left', bbox_to_anchor = (2.2, 0.5), ncol = 1, fontsize = 10)
    self.widget.canvas.draw()                                                       
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()                              
    sleep(.5)   # HERE IS THE SLEEP INTRODUCED
else:
    global last_read     
    last_read = measure   
    self.statusbar.showMessage('Idle')  
    f.close()          
    self.ser.write('C')  
    try:                          
        for i in range(1000):
            self.ser.timeout = .1
            a = self.ser.readline()
            self.statusbar.showMessage('Deleting reads in the serial buffer')  
            if a == 'Last':
                break 
    except:
        self.ser.close()
```

The GUI runs just fine (use less than 2 % CPU) untill I call this part of the code when I press the startButton (which stays checked untill I press it again).

Comment: Just to update the thread. I run updates to my Ubuntu Linux and now the exact same program is taking ~38% of CPU usage. Thank you for the help Mark.